# What's wrong with this program, it terminates?

Tags: c++

The following program terminates after calculation selection and nothing happens further. So my question is what is wrong i'm doing? Kindly someone check this program and notify me my mistakes. This program is a calculator, which asks user to select the calculation method i.e addition, division or multiplicatio etc. and then shows the result after calculations 
Pic: http://i43.tinypic.com/2hykpjp.png
 Pardon me as i'm new to C programming.

```
main()
{
  // declaration
  int add,sub,mul,div,selection;
  float a,b,c;
  // prompt user to select a method
  cout << "Calculator, which performs addition,subtraction,multiplication and division: add,sub,mul,div";
  cout << "Please enter your selection (for example: mul): ";
  cin >> selection;
  if (selection = add)
  {
             // prompt user to enter values
             cout << "Please enter first value: ";
             cin >> a;
             cout << "Please enter second value: ";
             cin >> b;
             // calculations
             c = a + b;
             // result
             cout << "Answer: " << c;
  }
  if (selection == sub)
  {
             // prompt user to enter values
             cout << "Please enter first value: ";
             cin >> a;
             cout << "Please enter second value: ";
             cin >> b;
             // calculations
             c = a - b;
             // result
             cout << "Answer: " << c;
  }
  if (selection == mul)
  {
             // prompt user to enter values
             cout << "Please enter first value: ";
             cin >> a;
             cout << "Please enter second value: ";
             cin >> b;
             // calculations
             c = a * b;
             // result
             cout << "Answer: " << c;
  }
  if (selection == div)
  {
             // prompt user to enter values
             cout << "Please enter first value: ";
             cin >> a;
             cout << "Please enter second value: ";
             cin >> b;
             // calculations
             c = a / b;
             // result
             cout << "Answer: " << c;
  }
}
```

Comment: That does not look like C but C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example of running the program, what you are trying to do is to input strings, such as **add**, and then compare them. What you are actually doing in your program is that **selection**, **add**, **sub** etcetera are integer variables, which can be used only to store integers.

You must declare **selection** as a string variable, and compare its value to string constants, something like this:

```
string selection;
```

And then:

```
if (selection == "add")
```

Comment: Okay people so actually mistakes were in my // declaration part. I was declaring wrong variables. Now i'm using
    #include
        main()
        {
          // declaration
          int x, y, z, d, e;
          x = 1;
          y = 2;
          d = 3;
          e = 4;
          float a,b,c;
          // rest of my prog
        }

And i replaced add with x, sub with y, mul with d and div with e. Also replaced 'Selection' with 'z'. And it wroked this time. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized anything here:

```
int add,sub,mul,div,selection;
```

You take the value for `selection` using `cin >> selection;` but what are these things supposed to mean:

```
if (selection = add)
if (selection == sub)
if (selection == mul)
if (selection == div)
```

Variables with storage class `auto` are not initialized to any default value.

Answer (score 1):

No initialization in the following line.

```
 int add,sub,mul,div,selection;
```

Initialize these variables with unique values (say 0 for add, 1 for sub).
Also, in comparison

```
 selection = add
```

Use

```
selection == add
```

Use `else if` instead separate ifs. It will improve the performance. In your case, it will compare each and every condition. It is shown as an example.

```
  if (selection = add)
     {
                // prompt user to enter values
                cout << "Please enter first value: ";
                cin >> a;
                cout << "Please enter second value: ";
                cin >> b;
                // calculations
                c = a + b;
                // result
                cout << "Answer: " << c;
     }
  else if (selection == sub)
     {
                // prompt user to enter values
                cout << "Please enter first value: ";
                cin >> a;
                cout << "Please enter second value: ";
                cin >> b;
                // calculations
                c = a - b;
                // result
                cout << "Answer: " << c;
     }

//Rest of your program.
```